# How can I get the final status of a completed Jenkins job via API?

Tags: api, jenkins

I make a call like:

http://jenkins.mysite.com/job/MYJOB/api/json?depth=2&tree=builds%5Bactions%5Bparameters%5Bname%2Cvalue%5D%5D%2Cnumber%2Cresult%5D

and get a result like:

```
{
    "builds": [{
        "actions": [{
            "parameters": [{
                "name": "JT_BUILD_ID",
                "value": "1274"
            }]
        }, {}, {}, {}, {}],
        "number": 3,
        "result": "SUCCESS"
    }, {
        "actions": [{
            "parameters": [{
                "name": "JT_BUILD_ID",
                "value": "1273"
            }]
        }, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}],
        "number": 2,
        "result": "SUCCESS"
    }, {
        "actions": [{
            "parameters": [{
                "name": "JT_BUILD_ID",
                "value": "0"
            }]
        }, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}],
        "number": 1,
        "result": "SUCCESS"
    }]
}
```

I am passing JT_BUILD_ID so I can match to this run of MYJOB.

When I find the matching JT_BUILD_ID, I look at result and when I see SUCCESS I assume I am done.  But the job is still running do to post build actions.

How can I both match the instance of the build (using the parameter JT_BUILD_ID) and detect the final status of the job?

Comment: which kind of script do you use towards the API ? javascript/python ? "How you passing JT_BUILD_ID" in the question, in API directly ?

Comment: just making a http call in python (no library, just raw code)
like:
/job/MYJOB/buildWithParameters?delay=0sec&token=XBUILD&JT_BUILD_ID=1276

Comment: in your case, why not use if statement to check ? let's assume json_result is above string, build_no is what you want. then `filter(lambda x: x["actions"][0]["parameters"][0]["name"]=='JT_BUILD_ID' and x["number"]==build_no, json_result["builds"])`

Comment: I think you are not understanding my question.  This is not a parsing problem... I see the result 'SUCCESS' but the build is not done, it still has post build commands left to run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is another key `building` under `builds`, if the post-build is still working, the status will be kept as `true`. It turns to `false` when the job is totally completed.

Therefore you can add extra check for `building == false`, the final url looks like below

[https://ci.jenkins-ci.org/view/Libraries/job/lib-jira-api/api/json/?pretty=true&depth=2&tree=builds[actions[parameters[name,value]],number,result,building]](https://ci.jenkins-ci.org/view/Libraries/job/lib-jira-api/api/json/?pretty=true&depth=2&tree=builds%5Bactions%5Bparameters%5Bname,value%5D%5D,number,result,building%5D)

The result could be like below in your case if latest build is ongoing (in post-build phase)

```json
{
  "builds": [{
    "actions": [{
        "parameters": [{
            "name": "JT_BUILD_ID",
            "value": "1274"
        }]
    }, {}, {}, {}, {}],
    "building" : true,
    "number": 3,
    "result": "SUCCESS"
  }, {
    "actions": [{
        "parameters": [{
            "name": "JT_BUILD_ID",
            "value": "0"
        }]
    }, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}],
    "building" : false,
    "number": 1,
    "result": "SUCCESS"
  }]
}
```